# In VSCode, I am currently inside WSL: Amazon, and I'm getting a SAM debug: missing AWS credentials (Toolkit is not connected)

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, .net-core, aws-lambda

I am currently trying to get VSCode running with the Amazon Linux distribution v2. I get all the way up to the run step, and then it falls over with "SAM debug: missing AWS credentials (Toolkit is not connected)" and "SAM CLI not configured".

Debug log below

```
2023-01-27 19:42:44 [WARN]: SAM debug: missing AWS credentials (Toolkit is not connected)
2023-01-27 19:42:45 [INFO]: SAM CLI location: [object Object]
2023-01-27 19:42:46 [INFO]: SAM CLI location: [object Object]
2023-01-27 19:42:47 [INFO]: SAM CLI location: [object Object]
2023-01-27 19:42:47 [INFO]: SAM CLI location: [object Object]
2023-01-27 19:42:48 [INFO]: Preparing to debug locally: Lambda "HelloWorld::HelloWorld.Function::FunctionHandler"
2023-01-27 19:42:48 [INFO]: Building SAM application...
2023-01-27 19:42:48 [INFO]: SAM CLI location: [object Object]
2023-01-27 19:42:48 [INFO]: Command: (not started) [/usr/local/bin/sam build --build-dir /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctkkE0arS/output --template /src/sample/template.yaml]
2023-01-27 19:42:48 [INFO]: SAM CLI not configured, using SAM found at: '/usr/local/bin/sam'
2023-01-27 19:42:54 [INFO]: Build complete.
2023-01-27 19:42:54 [INFO]: Installing .NET Core Debugger to /src/sample/src/HelloWorld/.vsdbg...
2023-01-27 19:42:56 [INFO]: Command: (not started) [/src/sample/src/HelloWorld/.vsdbg/installVsdbgScript.sh -v latest -r linux-x64 -l /src/sample/src/HelloWorld/.vsdbg]
2023-01-27 19:42:56 [INFO]: Starting SAM application locally
2023-01-27 19:42:56 [INFO]: SAM CLI location: [object Object]
2023-01-27 19:42:56 [INFO]: AWS.running.command
2023-01-27 19:42:56 [INFO]: SAM CLI not configured, using SAM found at: '/usr/local/bin/sam'
2023-01-27 19:42:56 [INFO]: Command: (not started) [/usr/local/bin/sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction --template /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctkkE0arS/output/template.yaml -d 5858 --debugger-path /src/sample/src/HelloWorld/.vsdbg]
2023-01-27 19:42:58 [ERROR]: SamLaunchRequestError: Failed to run SAM application locally
```

I ran the sam local invoke again with the --debug option, and got the following:

```
2023-01-27 19:49:24,748 | Config file location: /src/sample/samconfig.toml
2023-01-27 19:49:24,748 | Config file '/src/sample/samconfig.toml' does not exist
2023-01-27 19:49:24,752 | Using SAM Template at /src/sample/template.yaml
2023-01-27 19:49:24,854 | Using config file: samconfig.toml, config environment: default
2023-01-27 19:49:24,854 | Expand command line arguments to:
2023-01-27 19:49:24,854 | --template_file=/src/sample/template.yaml --no_event --layer_cache_basedir=/root/.aws-sam/layers-pkg --container_host=localhost --container_host_interface=127.0.0.1 
2023-01-27 19:49:24,854 | local invoke command is called
2023-01-27 19:49:24,858 | No Parameters detected in the template
2023-01-27 19:49:24,868 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource HelloWorldFunction, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-01-27 19:49:24,868 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-01-27 19:49:24,868 | 0 stacks found in the template
2023-01-27 19:49:24,868 | No Parameters detected in the template
2023-01-27 19:49:24,876 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource HelloWorldFunction, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-01-27 19:49:24,876 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-01-27 19:49:24,876 | 2 resources found in the stack 
2023-01-27 19:49:24,876 | Found Serverless function with name='HelloWorldFunction' and CodeUri='./src/HelloWorld/'
2023-01-27 19:49:24,876 | --base-dir is not presented, adjusting uri ./src/HelloWorld/ relative to /src/sample/template.yaml
2023-01-27 19:49:24,883 | Found one Lambda function with name 'HelloWorldFunction'
2023-01-27 19:49:24,883 | Invoking HelloWorld::HelloWorld.Function::FunctionHandler (dotnetcore3.1)
2023-01-27 19:49:24,883 | Loading AWS credentials from session with profile 'None'
2023-01-27 19:49:24,979 | Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics
2023-01-27 19:49:24,988 | Sending Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'commandRun': {'requestId': 'cf4207d7-0554-4bcf-9e05-1dda22ed4df8', 'installationId': 'fb284138-2b0f-4c16-98b3-b665990567fc', 'sessionId': 'fd097a74-adc6-42c5-a6cc-de3bceaadc9b', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI', 'ci': False, 'pyversion': '3.7.10', 'samcliVersion': '1.71.0', 'awsProfileProvided': False, 'debugFlagProvided': True, 'region': '', 'commandName': 'sam local invoke', 'metricSpecificAttributes': {'projectType': 'CFN', 'gitOrigin': None, 'projectName': 'af2bdbe1aa9b6ec1e2ade1d694f41fc71a831d0268e9891562113d8a62add1bf', 'initialCommit': None}, 'duration': 125, 'exitReason': 'SSOTokenLoadError', 'exitCode': 255}}]}
2023-01-27 19:49:25,735 | HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)

Error: Error loading SSO Token: The SSO access token has either expired or is otherwise invalid.
Traceback:
  File "click/core.py", line 1055, in main
  File "click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
  File "click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
  File "click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 183, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 150, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 41, in wrapped
  File "samcli/cli/main.py", line 92, in wrapper
  File "samcli/commands/local/invoke/cli.py", line 116, in cli
  File "samcli/commands/local/invoke/cli.py", line 202, in do_cli
  File "samcli/commands/local/lib/local_lambda.py", line 133, in invoke
  File "samcli/commands/local/lib/local_lambda.py", line 185, in get_invoke_config
  File "samcli/commands/local/lib/local_lambda.py", line 285, in _make_env_vars
  File "samcli/commands/local/lib/local_lambda.py", line 341, in get_aws_creds
  File "botocore/credentials.py", line 435, in access_key
  File "botocore/credentials.py", line 527, in _refresh
  File "botocore/credentials.py", line 543, in _protected_refresh
  File "botocore/credentials.py", line 684, in fetch_credentials
  File "botocore/credentials.py", line 694, in _get_cached_credentials
  File "botocore/credentials.py", line 2053, in _get_credentials
  File "botocore/utils.py", line 2679, in __call__

An unexpected error was encountered while executing "sam local invoke".
Search for an existing issue:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Bug%3A%20sam%20local%20invoke%20-%20SSOTokenLoadError
Or create a bug report:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md&title=Bug%3A%20sam%20local%20invoke%20-%20SSOTokenLoadError
```

So it can't seem to authenticate against aws. I did this on another machine and it all worked without a hitch - I didn't have to provide an aws login. I am currently logged in to aws in the host system (Windows 11) using aws sso login. Does anyone know what's broken so I can fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I needed to go back into Docker, which I had previously installed, go into Settings > WSL Integration, make sure the "Enable integration with my default WSL distro" was ticked, and ensure Amazon2 was switched on. Then I was able to debug.